# dataframe generating own column names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-3.4

For a project, I want to create a script that allows the user to enter values (like a value in centimetres) multiple times. I had a While-loop in mind for this.
The values need to be stored in a dataframe, which will be used to generate a graph of the values.
Also, there is no maximum nr of entries that the user can enter, so the names of the variables that hold the values have to be generated with each entry (such as M1, M2, M3…M*n*). However, the dataframe will only consist of one row (only for the specific case that the user is entering values for).

So, my question boils down to this:
How do I create a dataframe (with pandas) where the script generates its own column name for a measurement, like M1, M2, M3, …M*n*, so that all the values are stored.

I can't acces my code right now, but I have created a While-loop that allows the user to enter values, but I'm stuck on the dataframe and columns part.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why do you need a dataframe for this, seems a bit overkill to me. You could just append to a dict if you don't need all the fancy stuff that pandas offers you

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @mischi, without additional context, pandas seems overkill, but here is an alternate method to create what you describe...

This code proposes a method to collect the values using a `while` loop and `input()` (your `while` loop is probably similar).

```
colnames = []
inputs = []
counter = 0

while True:
    value = input('Add a value: ')
    if value == 'q':                # provides a way to leave the loop
        break
    else:
        key = 'M' + str(counter)
        counter += 1
        colnames.append(key)
        inputs.append(value)


from pandas import DataFrame

df = DataFrame(inputs, colnames)  # this creates a DataFrame with 
                                  # a single column and an index
                                  # using the colnames

df = df.T                         # This transposes the DataFrame to
                                  # so the indexes become the colnames

df.index = ['values']             # Sets the name of your row
print(df)
```

The **output** of this script looks like this...

```
Add a value: 1
Add a value: 2
Add a value: 3
Add a value: 4
Add a value: q

       M0 M1 M2 M3
values  1  2  3  4
```

Answer (score 0):

`pandas` seems a bit of an overkill, but to answer your question.

Assuming you collect numerical values from your users and store them in a list:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

values = np.random.random_integers(0, 10, 10)
print(values)
array([1, 5, 0, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 9, 6])

columns = {}
column_base_name = 'Column'

for i, value in enumerate(values):
    columns['{:s}{:d}'.format(column_base_name, i)] = value

print(columns)
{'Column0': 1,
 'Column1': 5,
 'Column2': 0,
 'Column3': 1,
 'Column4': 1,
 'Column5': 1,
 'Column6': 4,
 'Column7': 1,
 'Column8': 9,
 'Column9': 6}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=columns, index=[0])

print(df)     
   Column0  Column1  Column2  Column3  Column4  Column5  Column6  Column7  \
0        1        5        0        1        1        1        4        1   

   Column8  Column9  
0        9        6
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! It now works. You might be right that a pandas dataframe is overkill...It seems that it is for now. I was looking for a more structured way of storing it than a list would allow.